# How can I setup autocompletion of early typed word in Sublime3?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3

How can I setup autocompletion of early typed word in Sublime3? 
For example in Notepad when I typing something, and if first symbols match I have popup window. 
Can I do such window in sublime 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `Preferences -> Settings - User` and add the following line:

```json
"auto_complete_selector": "source, text",
```

Save the file, and you should be all set, whether you're coding (`source`), typing in plain text, or using HTML or any other markup language like XML, Markdown, reStructuredText, LaTeX, etc. (`text`).